# SQL, cash totals for each SKU

Tags: sql

I have two tables; one has unique SKU numbers and description. The other has sales information; each purchase with SKU number. What i need to do is have one grand total per SKU. Right now it is listing each sku and each sale amount.

Comment: Try `select a.sku, a.description, sum(b.sales) from homework_items a join homework_sales b on a.sku = b.sku group by a.sku`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select SKU_number , sum(sale_amount)
from Description
group by SKU_number
```

Comment: That's what I thought. I am working with m-Power reporting system and it is a little strange. Thank you!

Comment: If the answer helped you, can you please mark it as correct or atleast upvote it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not seeing that you need description then I haven't included it, but a simple join on SKU will get the descriptions if you need. What you need is the Sum(Sales) I believe and a group by on SKU. For example heres the table I created:

```
SKU  OrderNumber  Sales
1A   1            15
1A   2            15
2B   3            35
1A   4            15
2B   5            35
3C   6            140
```

Then I ran

```
    select SKU, sum(sales) TotalSales from #Sales
    group by SKU
```

to get:

```
SKU  TotalSales
1A   45
2B   70
3C   140
```